# return json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects like

```
 objArray =   [{"color":"red", "width":5, "price":10},
    {"color":"green", "width":4, "price":8},
    {"color":"red", "width":7, "price":11}]
```

how can I return an array of objects where the color is red in javascript or jquery

Comment: Iterate over the array and add those objects to a new array where `color` is `"red"`. Or what's the problem? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements (btw. this is not a JSON object, it's just an array of objects).

Comment: i said array of objects in my description...

Comment: Then what's it about JSON in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var objArray =   [{"color":"red", "width":5, "price":10},
    {"color":"green", "width":4, "price":8},
    {"color":"red", "width":7, "price":11}]

 var tmp = []

 $.each(objArray,function(i,val){
     if(val.color == 'red')
     {
         tmp.push(objArray[i]);
     }
 });

 console.log(tmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

If by *"return"*, you mean return from a function, then you can use `Array.prototype.filter` like this:

```
return objArray.filter(function(v) { return v.color === 'red'; });
```

If you just wanted to save it to a variable, then it's just about the same:

```
var red_array = objArray.filter(function(v) { return v.color === 'red'; });
```

To cover for older browsers, use [the MDN `.filter()` shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function (fun /*, thisp */ ) {
        "use strict";

        if (this === void 0 || this === null) throw new TypeError();

        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun !== "function") throw new TypeError();

        var res = [];
        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in t) {
                var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
                if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t)) res.push(val);
            }
        }

        return res;
    };
}
```

---

Or if you want jQuery, use the [`$.map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method :

```
var arr = $.map( objArray, function(v) { if( v.color === 'red' ) return v; });
```

or the [`$.grep()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method :

```
var arr = $.grep( objArray, function(v) { return v.color === 'red'; });
```

**Examples:** http://jsbin.com/udawir/edit#javascript,live  *(change the Array passed to `$.each()` to log the resulting color values)*

Answer (score 0):

**Short & Simple:**

```
let objArray =   [ {"color":"red", "width":5, "price":10},
                   {"color":"green", "width":4, "price":8},
                   {"color":"red", "width":7, "price":11} ]


let newRedArray = objArray.filter(item => item.color === "red");
```

Hope it helps!